Is there a way to prevent log spamming with rsyslog?
I have AuditD running and one process like to constantly spawn children processes that do the same activity. Is there a way to have rsyslog not send in the same log message again? The hard part is the timestamp in the log changes so its not exactly the same.
I would tune out at the AuditD level but not sure how to tune out a process and their children processes.

This is in the nature of auditd.
If you are using auditd, and have a good reason for doing so, then instead of filtering its output, and risking to lose information, you should implement measures to cope with the resulting log volume, such as log rotation and compression.
